# Create a dictionary

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a dictionary using a function:

```py
df_revenue = pd.read_excel('Revenue.xlsx')
df_eps = pd.read_excel('EPS.xlsx')
df_op_revenue = pd.read_excel('op_revenue.xlsx')
available_tickers = df_revenue['ticker'].unique()
columns = df_revenue.columns.values.tolist()[1:]

item={}
for i in available_tickers:
    item={i:{'year':["2012", "2013", "2014","2015", "2016", "2017","2018","2019"] ,
             'eps':df_eps.loc[df_eps['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist(),
             'revenue':df_revenue.loc[df_revenue['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist(),
             'op_revenue':df_op_revenue.loc[df_op_revenue['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist()}}
    y=json.dumps(item)
    print(y)
```

What I am getting:

```
{"A": {"year": ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"], "eps": [[3.27, 2.13, 1.62, 1.2, 1.4, 2.1, 0.97, 0.0]], "revenue": [[6858000000, 3894000000, 4048000000, 4038000000, 4202000000, 4472000000, 4914000000, 0]], "op_revenue": [[1119000000, 386000000, 419000000, 522000000, 615000000, 841000000, 928000000, 0]]}}
{"AAL": {"year": ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"], "eps": [[-7.52, -6.54, 3.93, 11.07, 4.65, 2.61, 3.03, 0.0]], "revenue": [[24855000000, 26743000000, 42650000000, 40990000000, 40142000000, 42622000000, 44541000000, 0]], "op_revenue": [[148000000, 1399000000, 4249000000, 6204000000, 5060000000, 4231000000, 2656000000, 0]]}}
{"AAN": {"year": ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"], "eps": [[2.25, 1.58, 1.08, 1.86, 1.91, 4.06, 2.78, 0.0]], "revenue": [[2212827000, 2234631000, 2695033000, 3179756000, 3207716000, 3383708000, 3828923000, 0]], "op_revenue": [[277029000, 187058000, 139843000, 235941000, 242676000, 254699000, 269510000, 0]]}}
```

....

What I want to get:

```
{"AAL": {"year": [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015], "eps": [-5.6, -11.25, 4.02, 11.39], "revenue": [24855.0, 26743.0, 42650.0, 40990.0], "op_revenue": [148.0, 1399.0, 4249.0, 6204.0]}, "AAP": {"year": [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015], "eps": [5.29, 5.36, 6.75, 6.45], "revenue": [6205.003000000001, 6493.814, 9843.860999999999, 9737.018], "op_revenue": [657.315, 660.318, 851.71, 825.78]} ....
```

Basically I am getting each ticker in an individual dictionary when I want it in the same dict( As shows in what I want)

Comment: use `item.update({key:value})`

Comment: item.update didn't solve my problem of having all 'items' in one dictionary.

Comment: Or use a dictionary comprehension `myDict = {i : {'year':["2012", "2013", ...} for i in available_tickers}`.

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting years as a string in the list

```
df_revenue = pd.read_excel('Revenue.xlsx')
df_eps = pd.read_excel('EPS.xlsx')
df_op_revenue = pd.read_excel('op_revenue.xlsx')
available_tickers = df_revenue['ticker'].unique()
columns = df_revenue.columns.values.tolist()[1:]
item={}
for i in available_tickers:
   item={i:{'year':[2012, 2013, 2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018,2019] ,
         'eps':df_eps.loc[df_eps['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist(),         'revenue':df_revenue.loc[df_revenue['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist(),
         'op_revenue':df_op_revenue.loc[df_op_revenue['ticker']==i,columns].values.tolist()}}
y=json.dumps(item)
print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks good call. Do you have a solution for my question? How to have all 'items' in one dict instead of what am getting

Comment: can u elaborate what you want to get as an output